# Node.js uploaded file does not have path property

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am writing a file upload demo by multer in node.js.When form submit, I can get the file information, but it does not have path property.

### ejs file

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="file" name="photo">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </p>
</form>
```

### js

```
function (req, res ,next) {
    var img = req.file;
    var name = req.body.name || img.originalname;
    var path = require('path').join(dir, name);
    console.log(img);
}
```

### multer config

```
var multer = require('multer')();
app.post('/upload',multer.single('photo'),photos.submit(app.get('photos')));
```

### req.file

[image]

Comment: paste your multer configuration.

Comment: @Sam I have updated the question

Comment: You are using memStorage for storing file. That's why there is no path in req.file. Try changing this to: `var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })`. Replace **uploads/** with directory where you want to upload your file.

Comment: @Sam Thank you. It  works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using memStorage for storing file. That's why there is no path in req.file. 
Try changing this to: `var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })`. Replace uploads/ with directory where you want to upload your file.